# Trying to find a true condition for an empty record

Tags: java

OK. Im reading all the objects from an arraylist and grabbing thier names.

```
            for(Contractor o : fa.allValues){
                System.out.println(o.getName());
            }
```

This returns

```
Bobs Tools
                //The problem
Ic Remodeling
Fred and Nobby
Dogs With Tools
Dogs With Tools
Bitter Homes and Gardens
Etc etc
```

Now....when i create and add an object, i want to put the new object in any empty spaces that it finds. It should find an empty space when it comes to the 2nd record.

However........

```
String str = allValues.get(1).getName(); // where 1 is the location of the empty record
```

all the following returns false

```
System.out.println(str == "");
System.out.println(str == " ");
System.out.println(str == null);
```

I want to input a condition that returns true. What basic issue have i over looked here?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`, use `equals()` instead: `if (str.equals(""))`

Comment: Yet another martyr to `==` for `String`

Answer (score 2):

use equals for testing equality of string and not ==

Answer (score 1):

Your equality for an empty string is wrong. In java you should compare it using the equals-method.

I would recommend using the apache commons lang StringUtils.isEmpty() method.

Comment: I knew that, forgot that, and now know that again. Ta!